# Improving rCharts performance when plotting thousands points

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I'm trying to plot several thousands of points with rCharts package but I find it a bit slow with default parameters. I've tried to set turboThresold parameter to 0 but it didn't help.

Here is a table of performance :

- plotting 100 points : 00.05 s
- plotting 1000 points : 00.54 s
- plotting 10000 points : 17.00 s

Anyone can improve performance of this code ?

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
runApp(
  # User interface with 1 select box, 1 graph and 1 timer
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(  
    headerPanel(""),  
    sidebarPanel( 
      selectInput("value",NULL,choices=c(100,1000,10000), selected = 100)
    ),
    mainPanel(       
      showOutput("plot", "highcharts"),
      textOutput("timer")
    )   
  ), 
  # server side
  server = function(input, output){
    values<-reactiveValues()
    values$timer <- NULL
    # generating highcharts plot
    output$plot <- renderChart2({
      x <- 1:input$value
      df <- data.frame(x, x^2)
      names(df) <- c("x","xpower2")
      values$timer <- Sys.time()
      plot <- Highcharts$new()
      plot$series(
        data = toJSONArray2(df, json = F, names = F),
        name = "xpower2",
        type = "line"
      )
      plot$plotOptions(series=list(turboThreshold=0))
      return(plot)
    })
    # calculating time 
    output$timer <- renderText({
      input$value
      isolate({
        values$timer <- Sys.time() - values$timer
        return(paste("Time elapsed :", round(values$timer,3) , "seconds"))
      })
    })
  }
  )
)
```

Thanks for your help,
Matt

Comment: These commands do not help either :
  plot$plotOptions(series=list(animation = FALSE,enableMouseTracking =FALSE))

Comment: Try o disable shadows / animations / markers

Comment: Hi Sebastian. No improvement unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried to native Highcharts js, instead of rCharts? Then compare results?

Comment: I didn't manage to create a chart in native highchart with my R Shiny application unfortunately. But thanks to your remark, i found rHighcharts package and it seems to have better performance, time is divided by 5. So thanks for that :). If you have any example with native highchart in R, it'll be great anyway.

Comment: Sorry, Im not familiar with the rails.

Comment: Ok, thanks for everything Sebastian. I've found a nice project dealing with native highcharts : https://github.com/wch/shiny-jsdemo

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd recommend sending no more than around 3000 points to the browser with any browser graphing package. The options are endless but depend on the data. Outside of this, I couldn't speed it up with `rCharts` but here it is with `ggvis`.

```
library(shiny);library(ggvis)
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel('ggvis speed example'),  
  sidebarLayout(  
    sidebarPanel( 
      selectInput('points','Points To Plot',
                  choices=c(100,1000,10000,100000), selected = 1000)
    ),
    mainPanel(       
      ggvisOutput('ggvis')
    )   
  )), 
  server = function(input, output){
    reactive({
        1:input$points %>%             
        data.frame('x'=.,'y'=.^2) %>%
        ggvis(~x, ~y) %>% 
        layer_points() %>%
        add_axis("y", title_offset = 70) %>%
        add_tooltip(function(df) HTML(paste0('x: ',df$x,'<br>y: ',df$y)))
    }) %>% bind_shiny('ggvis')
  }
  )
)
```

Comment: For some reasons, I cannot use "ggvis" package. I guess I'll have to find another way of displaying my series. I'm considering to sample my large series into smaller ones, picking the right method to have the same appearance.

Comment: Heatmap? I'm sure there's some clearer ways to show that many points, depending on the purpose.

Comment: Not in my case, i'm dealing with time series.

Comment: If you can, maybe try `dygraphs` http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_dygraphs.html